# Print command result side by side

Tags: command-line, output

It is possible to print the result of 2 commands side by side...

Something like this

```
something `ls -l /a` `cat bla.txt`
```

result:

```
total 24                                                #while [ 1 = 1 ]; do
-rw-r--r-- 1 wolfy wolfy  194 Aug 13 08:50 c.in         #       echo "bla"
-rwxr-xr-x 1 wolfy wolfy   52 Sep 24 11:48 bla.sh       #done
-rwxr-xr-x 1 wolfy wolfy   38 Sep 24 11:48 bla1.sh      echo "bla"
-rwxr-xr-x 1 wolfy wolfy  147 Sep 24 11:54 ble.sh
```

I know that `pr` can do something like this with files, but I didn't find a way to do this for commands...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution)

```
pr -m <(cmd1) <(cmd2)
```

though in your case, since you have one command and one file:

```
ls -l | pr -m - bla.txt
```

Comment: Instead of `pr -m` one can use `paste`.

Comment: @RamchandraApte yes, though `paste` won't align them in columns like `pr -m` does.

Answer (score 6):

#### *TL;DR*

Consider using a combination of `paste` / `column` rather than `pr` to get more consistent results.

- Depending on your OS, `pr` incorrectly mixes in the columns when input lengths differ (Ubuntu, macOS) or even worse will print each input on a completely different pages (Centos 7)
- `pr` both prepends and appends extraneous output

FORMAT:

```
paste <(cmd1) <(cmd2) | column -s $'\t' -t
```

---

#### *Detailed Explanation*

A highly robust solution is possible through a combination of the `paste` and `column` commands.

Advantages of the `paste` / `column` approach over `pr`:

- Cleaner output due to no timestamp or page header information being prepended, nor a full screen of empty lines appended
- Columns always stay separate even when the input lengths are different

**Concrete example:**

```
paste <(ls -1 .) <(ls -1 ..) | column -s $'\t' -t
```

**Real-life output of `paste` / `column` technique on Ubuntu 16.04:**

```
jay-z@jaytaylor.com:~/go/src/github.com/jaytaylor/html2text
$ paste <(ls -1 .) <(ls -1 ..) | column -s $'\t' -t
LICENSE            archiveify
README.md          go-hostsfile
html2text.go       html2text
html2text_test.go  jaytaylor
testdata           mockery-example
shipbuilder
stoppableListener
tesseract-web
```

### See also: [combine text files column-wise](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16443/combine-text-files-column-wise/16465)

#### For Comparison: `pr` on various platforms

***TL;DR:* `pr` behavior is inconsistent across Linux flavors.**

Output of `pr` version on **Ubuntu**:

```
jay-z@jaytaylor.com:~/go/src/github.com/jaytaylor/html2text
$ pr -m <(ls -1 .) <(ls -1 ..)


2017-05-25 15:50                    /dev/fd/62                    Page 1


LICENSE                 archiveify
README.md               go-hostsfile
html2text.go                html2text
html2text_test.go           jaytaylor
testdata                mockery-example
                    shipbuilder
                    stoppableListener
                    tesseract-web
```

Output of `pr` version on **OS X / macOs**:

```
jay-z@jaytaylor.com:~/go/src/github.com/jaytaylor/html2text
$ pr -m <(ls -1 .) <(ls -1 ..)


May 25 08:55 2017  Page 1


LICENSE                 archiveify
README.md               go-hostsfile
html2text.go                html2text
html2text_test.go           jaytaylor
testdata                mockery-example
                    shipbuilder
                    stoppableListener
                    tesseract-web

<... remainder of screen filled with blank lines ...>
```

Output of `pr` version on **Centos**:

(Surprisingly the behaviour of `pr` under Centos 7 differs from that of all other platforms tested)

```
jay-z@jaytaylor.com:~/go/src/github.com/jaytaylor/html2text
$ pr <(ls -1 .) <(ls -1 ..)


2017-05-25 15:59                    /dev/fd/63                    Page 1


LICENSE
README.md
html2text.go
html2text_test.go
testdata

<... remainder of screen filled with blank lines ...>

2017-05-25 16:21                    /dev/fd/62                    Page 1


archiveify
go-hostsfile
html2text
jaytaylor
mockery-example
shipbuilder
stoppableListener
tesseract-web

<... remainder of screen filled with blank lines ...>
```

Comment: nice. better than the accepted answer. but still, colored output breaks everything. `paste <(screenfetch) <(echo hi |cowsay -W 20) |column -s $'\t' -t`

Comment: Glad to hear you found it helpful.  Cheers!

Comment: it is helpful but not working properly with colors. see above command. do you know what to do about this? thanks

Comment: Yes, colors will always mess it up.  Stripping colors beforehand from the input may do the trick, for examples see these resources: http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3584/remove-color-codes-special-characters-with-sed or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/140251/strip-color-on-os-x-with-bsd-sed-or-any-other-tool

Comment: This is a more complete answer and should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `screen` like this:

In `screen` type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>|</kbd> for vertical and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> for horizontal split.

- jump to next display region: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd>
- remove current region: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd>
- remove all regions but the current one: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>Q</kbd>

start `ls -l /a` in the right half and `cat bla.txt` in the left.

Comment: Where `screen` works, `tmux` works too.